# Is $SL_n(\mathbb Z)$ or $\Gamma_1(N)$ a coxeter group?

Tags: group-theory, modular-group

If they are coxeter group, they will be generated by some order-2 elements, with eigenvalues $\pm 1$ and characteristic polynomial $(x-1)^m(x+1)^n$. And I don't know how to continue.

Comment: For $n = 2$ you can check that $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ has the wrong abelianization (the abelianization of a Coxeter group is $2$-torsion) and similarly for $N$ such that $\Gamma_1(N)$ is torsion-free.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan Thanks!

Comment: For $n>2$ no finite index subgroup is isomorphic to a finite index subgroup of a Coxeter group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870810000307#:%7E:text=Coxeter%20groups%20are%20virtually%20special%E2%98%86&text=In%20this%20paper%20we%20prove,a%20right%2Dangled%20Coxeter%20group.) Coxeter groups are virtually inside right angled Artin groups which are (bi)automatic. Hence Coxeter groups cannot contain infinite nilpotent non-virtually abelian groups. On the other hand infinite $SL(n, .)$ with $n\ge  3$ and its finite index subgroups contain non-virtually abelian infinite nilpotent groups of uni-upper-triangular matriced. Therefore no finite index subgroup of  an infinite $SL(n, .)$, $n\ge 3$, can embed into a Coxeter group.